# Как добавить анимацию сдвига элементов после удаления одного из них

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Динамически добавляю картинки, после загрузки картинки появляется Thumbnail с анимацией (к примеру fadeIn). При удалении исчезает с анимацией (к примеру fadeOut). Если удалить вторую картинку, все что после нее резко сдвигаются к первой. Собственно вопрос: Как сделать этот сдвиг анимированным?

```js
$(document.body).click(function() {
  $("div:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
});


$('#two').click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  margin: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  display: none;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
}

#one {
  background: #f00;
}

#two {
  background: #0f0;
}

#three {
  background: #00f;
}

#four {
  background: #0ef;
}

#five {
  background: #0af;
}

</style>
```

```html
<span>Создать</span>
<br>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
<div id="six"></div>
```

Создайте несколько элементов а потом кликните по зелёному для удаления.

https://jsfiddle.net/3pzb08et/1/

Comment: где код? надо ваш код увидеть.

Comment: Вместо `.fadeOut()` попробуйте поставить `.slideUp()`...

Comment: @AGS17, А какая разница? Всё равно после того как елемент исчезнет  соседние сдвинутся.

Comment: @VadimPedchenko этот метод скрывает элемент посредством изменения высоты блока, как следствие подпрыгивания элемента списка не будет.

Comment: @AGS17, Всё то же, только с другой анимацией)

Comment: @VadimPedchenko тогда добавьте код, чтобы хоть видеть что вы там скрываете ([править вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/678386/edit))

Comment: @AGS17, Добавил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте анимировать с помощью CSS свойства `transition` и добавления-удаления класса с `width: 0`:

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  $('div.hidden:first').removeClass('hidden');
});

$('div').click(function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation(); // чтобы не дергалось событие клика по документу
  $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  margin: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  transition: width .4s;
}

div.hidden {
  width: 0px;
}

#one {
  background: #f00;
}

#two {
  background: #0f0;
}

#three {
  background: #00f;
}

#four {
  background: #0ef;
}

#five {
  background: #0af;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="two" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="three" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="four" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="five" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="six" class="hidden"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Такое устроит? `$(this).hide( "slow" );`

http://jsfiddle.net/3pzb08et/2/

Comment: Уже лучше))) А с другой анимацией никак? Ну чтобы соседние блоки плавно сдвигались.

Comment: а сейчас как, не плавно?  http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Нет, всё отлично, просто имеется ввиду нельзя ли использовать что-то другое вместо hide, но чтобы они также плавно сдвигались.

Comment: @VadimPedchenko  посмотрите http://api.jquery.com/animate/